# Flagging bug in mobile web application

Tags: bug, mobile-web, mobile-safari

While browsing the mobile website on an iPod touch, I encountered the following problem while trying to flag a question as too broad.  The textfield for entering an answer to the question is obscuring the last few flagging options:

[image]

I did not have any problems with the initial flag screen. Only after I selected the "It should be closed for another reason.." option did the textview obscure my view.

This was while viewing the website on Safari. Still on iOS 6.